# update service from directive that uses it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It is possible for a directive to update a service and then use the updated version?

In my service (cfg), I have a variable and an update function...

```
  var test = "unfired";

  function updateTest(){
    console.log("LOG:","updateTest is firing");
    test = "fired";
  }
```

In the linking function of my directive I have

```
  scope.$watch(watcher, function(newVal, oldVal) {

    console.log("Before:",cfg.test);
    cfg.updateTest();
    console.log("After:",cfg.test);

  }); //scope.$watch
```

Even though the updateTest function is firing, the console logs the same value before and after.

Now if cfg were a controller instead of a service I would do something like

```
  function updateTest(){
    console.log("LOG:","updateTest is firing");
    test = "fired";
    cfg.$apply() //or cfg.$digest()
  }
```

But obviously that won't work. I have also tried injecting cfg to the controller and and $apply() to the link function...

```
    console.log("Before:",cfg.test);
    scope.$apply(function(){
      cfg.updateTest()
    });
    console.log("After:",cfg.test);
```

which did trigger updateTest(), but it did not update the cfg service *as the directive understands it*.

Perhaps another way to say it is that I would like to "reinject" the service into the directive.

If you are wondering why I'd like to do this, it's because I have a bunch of d3.js animations as directives that share the same scales, and I'd like certain events to trigger changes in the scales' domains from one directive to the others.

Comment: the test variable in your service is declared using `var`. This makes it private to the service, you cannot access this variable from outside. I am not sure how are you getting access to `cfg.test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a service to communicate between directives. Try using "broadcast". You can throw an event into the air and anybody listening will run whatever function you want. It works like this.

Directive 1:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event:updateTest');
```

Directive 2:

```
$rootScope.$on("event:updateTest", function (event, next, current) { ... }
```

Then you can deal with local instances of your 'test' variable, rather than a service 'global' variable.